# Database isn't recognizing created function? SQL State: 42883

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, coalesce, greenplum

NULL My function was created successfully, however when I attempt to use it I get the error message:

> ERROR: function coalesce2(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist
>   SQL state: 42883
>   Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

The purpose of my function is to grab the first NON NULL value and compare it to the value to the right of it. If the value to the right is not NULL then I will use that value, if it is then I use the COALESCE value. My function is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coalesce2(variadic anyarray)
RETURNS anyelement AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
FOR i IN 1 .. array_upper($1, 1)
LOOP
IF $1[i] IS NOT NULL THEN
  RETURN COALESCE($1[i+1], $1[i]);
END IF;
END LOOP;
RETURN NULL;  
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Here is the function in use:

> coalesce2
>      (
>      vw_header_to_node_13.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_12.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_11.subsetname, 
>      vw_header_to_node_10.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_9.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_8.subsetname, 
>      vw_header_to_node_7.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_6.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_5.subsetname, 
>      vw_header_to_node_4.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_3.subsetname, 
>      vw_header_to_node_2.subsetname, vw_header_to_node_1.subsetname, vw_header_to_node.subsetname, 
>      vw_header_to_node.setname)  AS prctr2

I don't have much experience with functions and I can't understand why it isn't recognizing the newly created function. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just as a test, can you try: `select coalesce2('uno'::varchar, 'two', 'three', 'four')` and see if it returns an error?  Your function and its inputs appear fine to me, but I'm obviously missing something

Comment: That does not work, either: ERROR: function coalesce2(character varying, unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Maybe that was my fault...  how about `select coalesce2('uno'::varchar, 'two'::varchar, 'three'::varchar, 'four'::varchar)`.  Not relevant when you're pulling explicitly from tables, but I didn't consider it for a dummy select

Comment: Still get the same:  ERROR: function coalesce2(character varying, character varying, character varying, character varying) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: That is crazy.  What version of PostgreSQL are you on?

Comment: It's Greenplum so it's 8.2 with their customizations.

Comment: For grins, I loaded your function on mine, and it worked fine -- just the way you described.  I'm on 9.3.  For what it's worth, I don't think it's the function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in an ARRAY to your function.

```
SELECT coalesce2(ARRAY['one', 'two', 'three']);
```

But this function will be expensive!  I wouldn't recommend using a PL/pgSQL function in inline SQL like this.  You would be better off using a CASE statement and creating a new table that doesn't rely on using functions to format the data.

And to answer your second question about how to use a CASE statement instead.

Note: your SQL example worries me because it looks like you are doing 10 LEFT OUTER JOIN statements which is costly.  It also is prefixed with "vw_" which makes me think you have 10 VIEWS and VIEWS can hide really bad SQL too.

I hope you aren't using VIEWS and lots of LEFT OUTER JOIN statements.  Analytics is done best with either a big flat table with every attribute you need in it that is stored column oriented or a classic Star Schema. Transform the data once and then use that output for analysis.

On to the answer.  Here is an example table with some data similar to yours:

```
    drop table if exists foo;
    create table foo
    (id int not null,
     col1 text,
     col2 text,
     col3 text,
     col4 text,
     col5 text,
     col6 text,
     col7 text,
     col8 text,
     col9 text,
     col10 text)
     distributed by (id);

    insert into foo (id, col1, col2) values (1, 'x1', 'x1');
    insert into foo (id, col2, col3) values (2, 'x2', 'x2');
    insert into foo (id, col3, col4) values (3, 'x3', 'x3');
    insert into foo (id, col4, col5) values (4, 'x4', 'x4');
    insert into foo (id, col5, col6) values (5, 'x5', 'x5');
    insert into foo (id, col6, col7) values (6, 'x6', 'x6');
    insert into foo (id, col7, col8) values (7, 'x7', 'x7');
    insert into foo (id, col8, col9) values (8, 'x8', 'x8');
    insert into foo (id, col9, col10) values (9, 'x9', 'x9');
    insert into foo (id, col10) values (10, 'x10');
```

So this is how it looks as a CASE statement:

```
    select id, case when col1 is not null then coalesce(col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) 
            when col2 is not null then coalesce(col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) 
            when col3 is not null then coalesce(col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) 
            when col4 is not null then coalesce(col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10)
            when col5 is not null then coalesce(col6, col7, col8, col9, col10) 
            when col6 is not null then coalesce(col7, col8, col9, col10) 
            when col7 is not null then coalesce(col8, col9, col10)
            when col8 is not null then coalesce(col9, col10)
            when col9 is not null then coalesce(col10)
            else col10 end
    from foo
    order by id;
```

And now as a SQL FUNCTION (not PL/pgSQL):

```
    create or replace function fn_coalesce2(text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text) returns text as
    $$
    select  case when $1 is not null then coalesce($2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) 
            when $2 is not null then coalesce($3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) 
            when $3 is not null then coalesce($4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10) 
            when $4 is not null then coalesce($5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10)
            when $5 is not null then coalesce($6, $7, $8, $9, $10) 
            when $6 is not null then coalesce($7, $8, $9, $10) 
            when $7 is not null then coalesce($8, $9, $10)
            when $8 is not null then coalesce($9, $10)
            when $9 is not null then coalesce($10)
            else $10 end;
    $$
    language sql;

    select id, fn_coalesce2(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10)
    from foo
    order by id;

    id | fn_coalesce2 
    ----+--------------
      1 | x1
      2 | x2
      3 | x3
      4 | x4
      5 | x5
      6 | x6
      7 | x7
      8 | x8
      9 | x9
     10 | x10
    (10 rows)
```

Comment: How could a CASE statement be used? Wouldn't that me taxing, as well?

Comment: Like PostgreSQL, Greenplum does not know how to interpret PL/pgSQL directly.  It has to pass it to a special handler which "costs" more than if it was handled internal to the database.  Greenplum is an Analytics database where you typically have full table scans on millions or billions of rows so adding millions of billions of extra PL/pgSQL executions adds up.  CASE is a built-in function so there is less overhead.   The general rules is to use PL/pgSQL to encapsulate transformation logic and SQL functions for in-line SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting Postgres features are not supported by Greenplum, because it uses old Postgres 8.2 version.

1. Function can receive only ARRAY parameter for anyarray pseudo-type. In your case it can be

   ```
   select coalesce2(ARRAY[v1.a, v2.a, v3.a]) AS prctr2  from v1,v2,v3
   ```
2. PL/SQL function cannot use 'anyarray' parameter. I have received following error in attempt to test your function on my Greenplum instance

   ```
   ERROR:  plpgsql functions cannot take type anyarray
   ```
3. Function with provided signature can be implemented with 'sql' language. It will work with any type/size of array.

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coalesce2(variadic anyarray)
   RETURNS anyelement AS
   $BODY$
   select
       first_value(c) over(order by s)
   from (
       select c,s
       from (
           select
               unnest($1) c, 
               generate_series(1,array_upper($1,1)) s
       ) b
       where c is not null
   ) a;
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
   ```
4. I do not know context of using this function, but it looks like you join views/tables for array creation. You can see that my function 'unnest' array back to table, so maybe you can create more effective SQL query instead of using function with array parameter.